# HTML page color overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to overlay a color w/ transparency over the entire page, except for one div? I want something like twitter.com's "tweetbox", where a div appears and everything else on the page sort of "falls to shadows" until the div is dismissed. How might one do this with only HTML, CSS, Javascript, and jQuery?

Comment: You mean a modal dialog? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: @Shmiddty I really didn't think this one through...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to overlay a color w/ transparency over the entire
>   page, except for one div?

yes. (its called a "Modal" btw. You can download one by searching for "lightbox", "modal", "javascript dialog box", and probably many other similar terms.)

create a div that has 100% height, 100% width, position fixed, top 0, left 0, and a z-index of some (high) number.

Then, create the other box and give it a z-index of that number + 1.

Comment: In some cases `position: fixed` is preferable to position absolute, if you're pretty sure your modal content is going to be smaller than the size of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I created an example of how I would do that:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/iqoduh/2/edit)*

```
$('.box').click(function(){
  $('.box').css({zIndex:0});
  $(this).css({zIndex:101});
  $('#overlay').fadeTo(300,1);
});

$('#overlay').click(function(){
  $(this).stop().fadeTo(300,0,function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```